# Magento showing Price Difference in configurable Products

Tags: magento-1.7, configurable-product

I have a Magento website where I have set up many configurable products with the different price.

There configurable options drop-down shows its associated products with the price difference. While I want to show their exact price instead of their price-difference.

You can have a look at my website page "http://www.tuneablestest.com/cds-dvds" and also see below image to understand my problem clearly-

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBoom.png]

I hope my problem is clear to all and please suggest me anyway to show their actual price.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225093/replace-price-difference-with-actual-price-in-magento-configurable-product-optio

Answer (score 0):

shashank,You have set different `additional price` from admin which has  been add or deducted from main price on basic  of  variance selection.This price is not calculated as product main price.
Goto your  `admin>catalog>Manage Product` select any configurable product and goes it `Associated Product tab` >here you can set additional price for `variance wise`.
Which is show on product price.Shows when you have cart a configurable product.Using json code and j`avscript magento is set price with variance wise frontend UI`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you create a configurable product it doesn't matter what's the price of simple products -- these prices are ignored completely. So if you want to sell a simple product A which has price $29.99 and a simple product B ($39.99) then you must create a configurable product, set its price to $29.99 and open Associated product tab. Add products you want to associate with this configurable product. After adding them a block named Super product attributes configuration appears which contains options and price differences. Leave product A price empty and put 10 (+$10) to product B price field and voila: different simple product have different price.

There's actually an extension that allows you to use simple product prices instead of price differences, but it's kind of tricky to set up. Since it's free extension, I hope nobody complains about me pasting its link here:

https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple

**I hope this will help you.**